# How to apply percentage coupon to specific type of product instead of complete order in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: module, percentage, rules, drupal-commerce, coupon

In Drupal Commerce, how do I apply a percentage coupon to specific type of product instead of complete order amount?

Can this be done using `rules` or do I have to create some custom module?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Commerce Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) 7.x-2.0 and [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount), you can set your discounts to be applied to the entire order or certain products.

[image: Screen shot of Discount interface]

Comment: thnks for the reply ,but i want to know in which rule I have to apply this condition?